# Code First with Entity Framework Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two model classes with one to many relationship. When I `add-migration` and `update-database` cammand then it returns the following message:

> To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.

How can I fix this issue?

```
public class Dictionary
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Word { get; set; }
    public int PartOfSpeechId { get; set; }

    public PartOfSpeech PartOfSpeech { get; set; }
}

public class PartOfSpeech
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Dictionary> Dictionary { get; set; }
}
```

Seed method:

```
var word = new Dictionary() { Word = "about", PartOfSpeechId = 6 };

context.Dictionaries.Add(word);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: if database or system is not in production, then you can simply remove database and again create it using migrations..

Comment: I removed DB and created from the beginning but it still is this issue.

Comment: first of all try not to pass PartOfSpeechId  in seeders. looks like your primary key columns are Identity, so it will not allow you to pass Id expliciltey..